# Concat and minify JS files in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

Is there any module in NodeJS to concatenate and minify JavaScript files?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're using Connect, then I've had good luck with [Connect-Assetmanager](https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager)

Comment: This is the One True Way. You shouldn't need an extra step between saving a file and refreshing the browser window.

Comment: This is not a universal answer, as concating and minifying may have nothing to do with Connect!

Comment: @edward that package looks a little out date (4/5 years) which has not been maintained

Answer (score 62):

I recommend using [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/) which is a JavaScript parser / mangler / compressor / beautifier library for NodeJS.

If you are interested in automation tools that do more than simply concatenate and minify files, there are the following solutions:

- [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/) is a task-based command line build tool for JavaScript projects. The current version has the following built-in tasks:

  1. concat - Concatenate files.
  2. init - Generate project scaffolding from a predefined template.
  3. lint - Validate files with [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/).
  4. min - Minify files with [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/).
  5. qunit - Run [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DQUnit%26redirect%3Dno) unit tests in a headless [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) instance.
  6. server - Start a static web server.

Besides this tasks there's a lot of [plugins](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/gruntplugin) available.

- [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) is a toolkit that will help you automate painful or time-consuming tasks in your development workflow. For web development (if that's your thing) it can help you by doing CSS preprocessing, JS transpiling, minification, live reloading, and much more. Integrations are built into all major IDEs and people are loving gulp across PHP, .NET, Node.js, Java, and more. With over 1700 plugins (and plenty you can do without plugins), gulp let's you quit messing with build systems and get back to work.
- [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) is a robust and opinionated set of tools, libraries, and a workflow that can help developers quickly build beautiful, compelling web apps.

  1. Lightning-fast scaffolding - Easily scaffold new projects with customizable templates (e.g [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)), AMD (via [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)) and more.
  2. Automatically compile CoffeeScript & Compass - Our [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) watch process automatically compiles source files and refreshes your browser whenever a change is made so you don't have to.
  3. Automatically lint your scripts - All your scripts are automatically run against [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) to ensure they're following language best-practices.
  4. Built-in preview server - No more having to fire up your own HTTP Server. My built-in one can be fired with just one command.
  5. Awesome Image Optimization - I optimize all your images using [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) and JPEGTran so your users can spend less time downloading assets and more time using your app.
  6. AppCache manifest generation - I generate your application cache manifests for you. Just build a project and boom. You'll get it for free.
  7. Killer build process - Not only do you get minification and concatenation; I also optimize all your image files, HTML, compile your [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) and [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) files, generate you an application cache manifest and, if you're using AMD, we'll pass those modules through r.js so you don't have to.
  8. Integrated package management - Need a dependency? It's just a keystroke away. I allow you to easily search for new packages via the command-line (e.g., yeoman search [jquery](http://jquery.com/)), install them and keep them updated without needing to open your browser.
  9. Support for ES6 module syntax - Experiment with writing modules using the latest ECMAScript 6 module syntax. This is an experimental feature that transpiles back to ES5 so you can use the code in all modern browsers.
  10. PhantomJS Unit Testing - Easily run your unit tests in headless WebKit via [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). When you create a new application, I also include some test scaffolding for your app.

Comment: This is the new hotness for functions like this. Highly recommend bumping this answer UP.

Comment: I am having so many problems with Yeoman right now. During development, I would have highly recommended it, but now I'm trying to build and it's giving me nothing but trouble. Media queries not working, JS errors where there were none. I came to this answer trying to find a js min/concat alternative to yeoman build.

Answer (score 33):

[UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/) is a Node module that is all about minifying javascript. I don't think it also joins files, but there might be an option I missed.

**Edit:**
With [UglifyJS 2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), it has built in concatenation as well.

If you want to do this inline in your node app it's really easy. This allows you to dynamically generate your minified/concatenated js script at runtime without using the grunt or yeoman way.

```
npm install uglify-js
```

and in your module:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var uglify = require("uglify-js");

var uglified = uglify.minify(['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js']);

fs.writeFile('concat.min.js', uglified.code, function (err){
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Script generated and saved:", 'concat.min.js');
  }      
});
```

Comment: also the minification part is the difficult part. Joining those files can be coded in a couple of lines...

Comment: UglifyJS at version 2 does support file joins (concatentation) and can even export a source map for easier debugging.

Answer (score 13):

You'll be better using something like gulp / webpack to concat/organize/bundle your assets.

---

In order to join js file you can do as its done in twitter bootstrap makefile

```
cat js/bootstrap-transition.js js/bootstrap-alert.js js/bootstrap-button.js js/bootstrap-carousel.js js/bootstrap-collapse.js js/bootstrap-dropdown.js js/bootstrap-modal.js js/bootstrap-tooltip.js js/bootstrap-popover.js js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js js/bootstrap-tab.js js/bootstrap-typeahead.js > docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js
```

This is just a concatenation of files with an output to a js file

Then you can install uglify-js to minify js:

```
npm -g install uglify-js
```

And perform this command with your path/file.js ofc:

```
uglifyjs docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js -nc > docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

As mentioned in comments since uglifyjs 2 you could also do:

```
uglifyjs --compress --mangle -- input.js
```

Comment: The latest uglify doesn't let you pass options before the input file, I edited the line above

Comment: Latest [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) does [support this](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#usage): `uglifyjs --compress --mangle -- input.js`

Comment: Beware: uglifyjs doesn't support ES6 syntax, so I got `ERROR: Unexpected token: keyword «const»` which I did not expect! Advice is to babel it first, but that defeats the purpose and seems like a backwards step. Now looking for a simple dependency-free npm-installable minifier…

Answer (score 2):

If you like the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline approach, you should try my [connect-assets](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets) library.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for but [Enderjs](https://github.com/ender-js/Ender) could work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely suggest the Closure Compiler's simple mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try these two plugins for Grunt

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-concat

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-uglify

You can install everything you need like so:

```
npm install grunt
npm install grunt-cli
npm install grunt-contrib-concat
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify
```

Then create your grunt file, like so:

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      options: {
        process: function(src, path){
          return '\n/* Source: ' + path + ' */\n' + src;
        }
      },
      src: [
        '../src/**/*.js'
      ],
      dest: '../bin/app-debug.js'
    },
    uglify: {
      src: '../bin/app-debug.js',
      dest: '../bin/app.js'
    },
    watch: {
      options: {
        atBegin: true,
        event: ['all']
      },
      src: {
        files: '../src/**/*.js',
        tasks: ['concat']
      },
      dist: {
        files: '../bin/app-debug.js',
        tasks: ['uglify']
      },
    }
  }

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
}
```

Finally, type `grunt` in the terminal and Grunt will start watching your JavaScript files for changes and automatically concat and uglify them (whenever you save a change to your js files in ../src/

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `uglify-js`, your code uses some of the latest [ES6 features (ECMAScript 2015)](http://es6-features.org/) and it just gave you back parse errors on the first run, then install *uglify-**e**s*:

```
npm install uglify-es -g
```

Or:

```
npm install mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony
```

The explanation is in [uglify-js-es6 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js-es6):

> This is a temporary package containing the latest release of the ['harmony' branch](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony) of uglifyjs ([UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2)).

You can still run it normally with the `uglifyjs` command. A compress and mangle example:

```
uglifyjs -c -m -o js/es6stuff.js -- js/es6stuff/*.js
```

Which will produce a single file with all the JS files of a folder. The double dash (`--`) just prevents input files being used as option arguments.

Comment: To the downvoter, will you please explain what is wrong with this answer?